# Reading Tables and columns in SQL SERVER using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is it possible to determine the tables and its column in SQLserver in a particular database using c#?

Can any one guide me in this issue?

Comment: Have a look at this link [GetSchema - DbConnection.GetSchema in ADO.NET 2.0 - Retrieve Databases Tables Columns Views etc. from Database Connection](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/01/15/2734.aspx)

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/01/15/2734.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.aspx) from C#.

[Programming Specific Tasks in SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162175.aspx)